# How to remove selected topics from aggregator feed?

Tags: feeds

In my Drupal feed aggregator generating a separate website feed into my website. However, my client dislike some topics on that feed therefore, is it possible to remove selected topic from that feed ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you must implement [hook_aggregator_fetch](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!aggregator!aggregator.api.php/function/hook_aggregator_fetch/7) for this job.

Comment: Check rest of the API too: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!aggregator!aggregator.api.php/7

Comment: Pardon me if I'm silly, If I place the above API described `hook_aggregator_fetch` function will that be enough ? If so how do I let know to the function that which topic should remove from which aggregator ? Could you pleas kindly clarify ?

Comment: Also I just found a another solution that categorizing all non-related feed topics to a separate aggregator category. That is very much likely doing the job but, how can I now unpublished that aggregator category ? Could you please elaborate a easy way ?

Comment: Start from reading about hook system in D7. Then implement this hook in your custom module, enable devel module and with help of dpm() function, check what is inside $feed variables passed to this hook